# Nmap scan does not show any device expect my own computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nmap

When I try to perform a nmap scan while connected to my home wifi, the only device that appears after the scan is my own pc even though I have a lot of phones and wifi connected to it.
I followed the following steps:

1. Found the IP address using ifconfig.
2. Used nmap -sn  command.

Comment: Please add to your post the entire `nmap` command that you use and the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Do you have wireless isolation enabled on your router?